# Cannot read property 'getODataEntitySet' of undefined

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am trying to use [SmartFilterBar](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.comp.smartfilterbar.SmartFilterBar) as following:

The view:

```
<smartFilterBar:SmartFilterBar id="smartFilterBar" considerSelectionVariants="true" entitySet="ZMD_C_CLASS_OBJECT">
    <smartFilterBar:controlConfiguration>
        <smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration key="ClassType" visibleInAdvancedArea="true" preventInitialDataFetchInValueHelpDialog="false"></smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration>
    </smartFilterBar:controlConfiguration>
</smartFilterBar:SmartFilterBar>
```

The controller of the view:

```
onInit: function () {
    const oModel = this.getModel("ClassSelect");
    this.getView().setModel(oModel);
},
```

The `dataSources` is defined in manifest as:

```
"dataSources": {
    "ZMD_C_CLASS_OBJECT_CDS": {
        "uri": "/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZMD_C_CLASS_OBJECT_CDS/",
        "type": "OData",
        "settings": {
            "odataVersion": "2.0",
            "localUri": "localService/metadata.xml"
        }
    }
}
```

and the model

```
"ClassSelect": {
    "uri": "/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZMD_C_CLASS_OBJECT_CDS/",
    "type": "sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel",
    "settings": {
        "defaultOperationMode": "Server",
        "defaultBindingMode": "OneWay",
        "defaultCountMode": "Request"
    },
    "dataSource": "ZMD_C_CLASS_OBJECT_CDS",
    "preload": true
}
```

The metadata from OData service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="1.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:sap="http://www.sap.com/Protocols/SAPData">
    <edmx:Reference Uri="https://example.net:80000/sap/opu/odata/IWFND/CATALOGSERVICE;v=2/Vocabularies(TechnicalName='%2FIWBEP%2FVOC_COMMON',Version='0001',SAP__Origin='S17CLNT100')/$value" xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx">
        <edmx:Include Namespace="com.sap.vocabularies.Common.v1" Alias="Common"/>
    </edmx:Reference>
    <edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="2.0">
        <Schema Namespace="ZMD_C_CLASS_OBJECT_CDS" xml:lang="de" sap:schema-version="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm">
            <EntityType Name="ZMD_C_CLASS_OBJECTType" sap:content-version="1">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="InternalClass"/>
                </Key>
                <Property Name="InternalClass" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="10" sap:display-format="NonNegative" sap:label="Int.Klasnr" sap:quickinfo="Interne Klassennummer"/>
                <Property Name="ClassType" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="3" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Klassenart" sap:value-list="standard"/>
                <Property Name="ClassNumber" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="18" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Klasse" sap:quickinfo="Klassennummer"/>
                <NavigationProperty Name="to_ClassTypeValueHelp" Relationship="ZMD_C_CLASS_OBJECT_CDS.assoc_6C4786335FC0AB4FBAF59609E841BB3C" FromRole="FromRole_assoc_6C4786335FC0AB4FBAF59609E841BB3C" ToRole="ToRole_assoc_6C4786335FC0AB4FBAF59609E841BB3C"/>
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="ZMD_I_CLASSTYPE_VHType" sap:content-version="1">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="ClassType"/>
                    <PropertyRef Name="ClassLang"/>
                </Key>
                <Property Name="ClassType" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="3" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Klassenart"/>
                <Property Name="ClassLang" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="2" sap:label="Sprachenschlüssel"/>
                <Property Name="ClassText" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="40" sap:label="Klassenartentext" sap:quickinfo="Bezeichnung der Klassenart"/>
            </EntityType>
            <Association Name="assoc_6C4786335FC0AB4FBAF59609E841BB3C" sap:content-version="1">
                <End Type="ZMD_C_CLASS_OBJECT_CDS.ZMD_C_CLASS_OBJECTType" Multiplicity="1" Role="FromRole_assoc_6C4786335FC0AB4FBAF59609E841BB3C"/>
                <End Type="ZMD_C_CLASS_OBJECT_CDS.ZMD_I_CLASSTYPE_VHType" Multiplicity="1" Role="ToRole_assoc_6C4786335FC0AB4FBAF59609E841BB3C"/>
            </Association>
            <EntityContainer Name="ZMD_C_CLASS_OBJECT_CDS_Entities" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true" sap:supported-formats="atom json xlsx">
                <EntitySet Name="ZMD_C_CLASS_OBJECT" EntityType="ZMD_C_CLASS_OBJECT_CDS.ZMD_C_CLASS_OBJECTType" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:deletable="false" sap:content-version="1"/>
                <EntitySet Name="ZMD_I_CLASSTYPE_VH" EntityType="ZMD_C_CLASS_OBJECT_CDS.ZMD_I_CLASSTYPE_VHType" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:deletable="false" sap:searchable="true" sap:content-version="1"/>
                <AssociationSet Name="assoc_6C4786335FC0AB4FBAF59609E841BB3C" Association="ZMD_C_CLASS_OBJECT_CDS.assoc_6C4786335FC0AB4FBAF59609E841BB3C" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:deletable="false" sap:content-version="1">
                    <End EntitySet="ZMD_C_CLASS_OBJECT" Role="FromRole_assoc_6C4786335FC0AB4FBAF59609E841BB3C"/>
                    <End EntitySet="ZMD_I_CLASSTYPE_VH" Role="ToRole_assoc_6C4786335FC0AB4FBAF59609E841BB3C"/>
                </AssociationSet>
            </EntityContainer>
            <Annotations Target="ZMD_C_CLASS_OBJECT_CDS.ZMD_C_CLASS_OBJECTType/ClassType" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
                <Annotation Term="Common.ValueList">
                    <Record>
                        <PropertyValue Property="Label" String="Value help classification type"/>
                        <PropertyValue Property="CollectionPath" String="ZMD_I_CLASSTYPE_VH"/>
                        <PropertyValue Property="SearchSupported" Bool="true"/>
                        <PropertyValue Property="Parameters">
                            <Collection>
                                <Record Type="Common.ValueListParameterInOut">
                                    <PropertyValue Property="LocalDataProperty" PropertyPath="ClassType"/>
                                    <PropertyValue Property="ValueListProperty" String="ClassType"/>
                                </Record>
                                <Record Type="Common.ValueListParameterDisplayOnly">
                                    <PropertyValue Property="ValueListProperty" String="ClassLang"/>
                                </Record>
                                <Record Type="Common.ValueListParameterDisplayOnly">
                                    <PropertyValue Property="ValueListProperty" String="ClassText"/>
                                </Record>
                            </Collection>
                        </PropertyValue>
                    </Record>
                </Annotation>
            </Annotations>
            <atom:link rel="self" href="https://example.net:80000/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZMD_C_CLASS_OBJECT_CDS/$metadata" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"/>
            <atom:link rel="latest-version" href="https://example.net:80000/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZMD_C_CLASS_OBJECT_CDS/$metadata" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"/>
        </Schema>
    </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

The compiler complains:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you try something like " entitySet="ClassSelect>ZMD_C_CLASS_OBJECT" in the smartFilter XML

Comment: The same error message.